# How to write an if statement with an interval?

Tags: if-statement, intervals, python-3.4

I can't figure it out.
 So far I have, but it isn't working, no matter what age I input it tells me I can be president.

```
import math 

(x) = input("Please enter your name:")
(y) = input("Please enter your age:")


print ("Hello" + x)
print ("Your age is" + y)

if ("y")> ("0") and ("y") < ("18"):
    print("You are a minor.")

if ("y")>=("18") and ("y") < ("25"):
    print("You can vote.")

if ("y")>= ("25") and ("y") < ("35"):
    print("You can rent a car.")

if ("y") >= ("35"):    
    print("You can be president.")
else:   
    print ("You have not entered a valid response. Must be a positive integer.")
```

How to get the intervals properly?

Comment: Are the things in parentheses supposed to be variables? You don't want tuples, do you?  (I'd get rid of the parentheses as that only adds confusion for you.)

Answer (score 2):

Writing an inequality range is a lot simpler in Python than doing distinct cut-offs; you can use math-style ranges.

Here's an example:

```
if 0 < y < 18:
    print("You are a minor.")
```

You shouldn't quote your variable, as that will treat it like a string literal.

Comment: If I do that, I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Age3.py", line 11, in <module>
    if 0 < y < 18:
TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()

Comment: Be sure to wrap your input call with the int function.  E.G. `y = int(input("Please enter your age."))`

Comment: When I add that correction:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\Age3.py", line 6, in <module>
    print ("Your age is" + y)
TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
>>>

Comment: I added a comma instead of + and it worked. YAY! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With help from the awesome Makoto, it's fixed! :D

import math

(x) = input("Please enter your name:")

(y) = int(input("Please enter your age:"))

print ("Hello" + x)

print ("Your age is" , y)

if 0 < (y) < 18:

print("You are a minor.")

elif 18 <= (y) < 25:

print("You can vote.")

elif 25 <= (y) < 35:

print("You can rent a car.")

elif (y) >= 35:

print("You can be president.")

else:

print ("You have not entered a valid response. Must be a positive integer.")